# Воспроизведение стерео файла в моно режиме в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio

На странице есть стандартный плеер нужно чтобы он воспроизводил аудио в моно режиме
`<audio class='player' id='_aud' src='url'>Браузер устарел</audio>`
пытался сделать так но это не заработало

```js
var element = document.getElementById('_aud');
Var source = context.createMediaElementSource(element);
var splitter = context.createSplitter(2);
source.connect(splitter);
var left = context.createGain();
var right = context.createGain();
splitter.connect(left,1,0);
splitter.connect(right,1,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного переписанный код отсюда у меня заработал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644328/using-channelsplitter-and-mergesplitter-nodes-in-web-audio-api

```
function CreateAud(audioElement, audioContext) {
       
        const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
       
        const volumeNodeL = new GainNode(audioContext);
        const volumeNodeR = new GainNode(audioContext);

        volumeNodeL.gain.value = 2;
        volumeNodeR.gain.value = 2;

        const channelsCount = 2; // or read from: 'audioSource.channelCount'
        const splitterNode = new ChannelSplitterNode(audioContext, { numberOfOutputs: channelsCount });
        const mergerNode = new ChannelMergerNode(audioContext, { numberOfInputs: channelsCount });

        audioSource.connect(splitterNode);
        splitterNode.connect(volumeNodeR, 0); // connect OUTPUT channel 0
        splitterNode.connect(volumeNodeL, 1); // connect OUTPUT channel 1
        //mono
        volumeNodeR.connect(mergerNode, 0, 1); // connect INPUT channel 1
        volumeNodeL.connect(mergerNode, 0, 1); // connect INPUT channel 1
        volumeNodeR.connect(mergerNode, 0, 0); // connect INPUT channel 0
        volumeNodeL.connect(mergerNode, 0, 0); // connect INPUT channel 0

        mergerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);            
    }
```

вызвал так

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
let arrAud = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
for (i in arrAud) {
  CreateAud(arrAud[i], audioContext);
}
```